# Callback кнопка VK через VK.Net

Tags: c#, vknet

Может кто использует VK.net для работы с Api VK?

Объясните в чем суть проблемы моей Callback кнопки?

```
var button = new MessageKeyboardButtonAction
        {
                Type = KeyboardButtonActionType.Callback,
                Label = "Нажмите",
                Payload = "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                
        };

        var keyboard = new KeyboardBuilder().AddButton(button,KeyboardButtonColor.Primary).Build();
        services.AddSingleton(keyboard);
```

В контроллере отправляю клавиатуру с кнопкой:

```
private void SendMessageToUser(long? fromId, string message)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomId = random.Next(0, 1000);

        MessagesSendParams sendParams = new()
        {
            RandomId = randomId,
            PeerId = fromId,
            Message = message,
            Keyboard = _keyboard
        };

        _vkApi.Messages.Send(sendParams);
```

Если создам `Type = KeyboardButtonActionType.Text,`
`, то ВК отправляет мне запрос в том числе с полем Payload.

Если `KeyboardButtonActionType.Callback`, индикатор на кнопке бесконечно крутится.
**Вк не отправляет мне никакого запроса** при этом.

Я ожидал получить запрос c типом message_event, и payload внутри, что бы вернуть ответ. Разве не так это должно работать? Помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

[Документация API VK о работе с кнопками](https://dev.vk.com/api/bots/development/keyboard#Callback-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)

[Документация VKNET где добавили Callback кнопки и метод работы с ними](https://github.com/vknet/vk/pull/1025/files)

`SendMessageEventAnswer`  что-то я не понимаю как с этим методом работать. Где я должен взять Event_ID , если мне его должен прислать VK API при нажатии на кнопку, но он мне ничего не присылает

Моя задача при нажатии на кнопку пользователем сменить режим бота на Аудиосообщения.
Я хочу получить запрос и изменить режим ответа бота. Желательно показав `show_snackbar`

Comment: А вы включили в настройках сообщества события типа `message_event`? В настройках должно называться как _Действие с сообщением_.

Comment: Смешно получилось. Спасибо )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы получить событие типа message_event нужно в настройках разрешить запросы типа "Действие с сообщением"